# Bind Escape key in Tmux

Tags: tmux

Since I have my <kbd>Caps-lock</kbd> key mapped to <kbd>Esc</kbd> (due to Vim), I'd also like it in tmux.

Specifically, I'm trying to set <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> as the prefix:

```
set -g prefix Escape-a
```

However, this isn't working, and I get the error `bad key: Escape-a`. Is this because <kbd>Esc</kbd> is not a modifier key? I'd really like this to work, as <kbd>Esc</kbd> is on the home row and very convenient to use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're on OS X you can achieve this with [karabiner](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner).

In your system preferences, change <kbd>Caps-lock</kbd> to <kbd>Control</kbd> instead of <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Then use karabiner to send <kbd>Esc</kbd> when you type <kbd>Control</kbd> by itself.

- karabiner preferences -> "Change Key" tab
- scroll down to "Change Control_L Key (Left Control)"
- check "Control_L to Control_L (+ When you type Control_L only, send Escape)"

[image: karabiner preferences]

This gives your left pinky easy access to both <kbd>Esc</kbd> *and* <kbd>Control</kbd>. You can exit Vim's insert mode the way you already are, and you can set <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> as your tmux prefix:

```
set -g prefix C-a
```

Comment: I had [Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en) installed, and that works ok too.

Answer (score 18):

This sequence:

```
set-option -g prefix Escape
unbind-key C-b
bind-key Escape send-prefix
```

...works for me. I'm using tmux-2.0

Comment: @mogsdad Why? Why did you have to edit my answer? o_0

Comment: New answers to old questions receive special scrutiny by being funneled into a special review process. Same thing for posts by new users. These are opportunities to both maintain the quality of content and to help educate new users. One guideline for reviewing posts is that reviewers should "Remove unnecessary introductions and closings". The age of the question had no relevance in your answer, so out it went. The rest is intended to make it easy to read - it's subjective, and you're free to reword it if you wish.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks @datasmurf. Works beautifully on OpenBSD 5.9

Comment: You may also consider Alt+Esc:  `set -g prefix M-Escape`

Answer (score 7):

I think this is not possible because `Esc` and `a` are 2 distinct keys. From what I know tmux doesn't allow key bindings with more than 1 key (for anything).

This is different from having, for example `Ctrl-a` as a prefix. Even though we type 2 keyboard keys to get it - `^A` is represented as a single character by both tmux and vim.